# How to transfer a matrix into a 2D ArrayList Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to accept a multidimensional matrix as input, such as

```
1 2 3
3 1 5
1 9 7
```

This is just an example, the one I'm using is a lot larger and different inputs may be different row lengths, row columns.
In my input, each row and column will be of equal length.
How do I go about storing the input as it appears, perhaps a two dimensional arraylist. I know that I will have to take the input as Strings and later parse them back into integers by `Integer.parseInt(string)` and I know Scanner's method `.split(" ")` splits an input by spaces, but how do i seperate lines so that the next row can be extracted.

Comment: So basically you want to get the 2D array elements as input in arraylist?

Comment: Yea, but if it can be entered into a regular 2D array, that would be okay. @AndrewWatson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you talk about splitting strings by spaces and parsing integers,
it seems your input is *matrix data as a string*.
You could first split to lines,
then to columns,
and parse to integers and collect in a 2D array or in a list of list.

```
String input = "1 2 3\n" +
    "3 1 5\n" +
    "1 9 7";

int[][] matrix = Arrays.stream(input.split("\n"))
    .map(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(" "))
        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
        .toArray())
    .toArray(int[][]::new);

List<List<Integer>> listOfLists = Arrays.stream(input.split("\n"))
    .map(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(" "))
        .map(Integer::parseInt)
        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here's the same thing in good old-fashioned iterative way,
if it's easier to understand:

```
String[] lines = input.split("\n");
int[][] matrix = new int[lines.length][];

for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    String[] columns = lines[i].split(" ");
    matrix[i] = new int[columns.length];
    for (int j = 0; j < columns.length; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(columns[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Although your answer is correct, it could only confuse a beginner. I don't think it is good idea to introduce streams and lambdas to someone struggling with splitting string on the new line - it would be good if you added classic, iterative way of doing that. :)

Comment: @Ladislav_M fair enough, I added that too

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a scanner that reads lines of input, here's one way

```
List<List<String>> matrix = new ArrayList<>();
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    matrix.add(Arrays.asList(sc.nextLine().split(" "));
}
```

Of course, change datatypes as you want

You could also store a flat Arraylist. Using the width of the matrix, you can translate rows and columns into the index

```
matrix[row][col] == list.get(col + row*matrix.width);
```